# Home automation with wifi module

Tags: networking, wifi, hardware, wireless, home-automation

Am from a software background and i don't know much about the hardware stuff.
I need to automate my home with the Raspberry pi 3 model B

I am planning to make my Raspberry pi as a local server and using a web application from phone to control all electric device of my home (ON/OFF)

I was planning for a staircase wiring that the device can control by both physical switches and also from my web interface

I have watched many tutorial for controlling electric device with Raspberry pi GPIO pins and Relay channel.But if go for this method i need to bring all the phase wire lead from all my 2 way switch to Raspberry pi or near by area to control each device by inputs from GPIO pins.I think its very hard to implement with these large ammount of wires

Is there any wifi module or board is available for Raspberry pi to connect with RPI over wifi and Trigger the channel relay based on the input from RPI.so i can done the wiring without bringing the phase lead from each device to RPI.

any link or update will helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actual Ricardo and user400344 misunderstood my requirement .Am not looking for smart plugs or wifi connected devices i actually need a electronic board which should listen to my raspberry command through wifi and should have output to connect to a channel relay..Thank you for your support

Comment: a smart plug is a device containing "an electronic board which should listen to my raspberry command through wifi and should have output to connect to a channel relay". Though you may want to google for 'wifi relay module', but then you have to add a power supply and so on, by which time you've recreated the insides of a smart plug.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ESP8266 based relay power modules. The ESP8266 is a WiFi and CPU chip and is widely used in Home projects for the purpose you are asking about.

I prefer to program them with Arduino IDE and uses MQTT as control protocol, and as a hub I uses Raspberry Pi with Mosquitto and Node Red to create the logic that control the different devices/modules.

I get my inspiration from:

https://tech.scargill.net/

Andreas Spiess channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCu7_D0o48KbfhpEohoP7YSQ

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about a project like this, but I would probably use WiFi to control smart plugs, and run OpenHAB on my Raspberry Pi.

So if you think that is an option, [check out OpenHAB](http://www.homeautomationforgeeks.com/openhab.shtml), and how to [hack/use a cheap smart plug](http://www.homeautomationforgeeks.com/openhab_http.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Use this software, it is scalable. The documentation is above average.

http://opennethome.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing we both do more of the same. I did not find any viable solution, so I decided sove it this way:

1)"Mainframe" - Rpi 3 - running a GUI/ Python code controlling all remote stations ( on/off/schedule )

2)"Remote station" - Rpi Zero W ( or Zero with wifi dongle )- at each point need to be controlled ( electric shades, CCTV cameras, light and more ),with a single/ double/ quad relay board designed to Rpi, packed nicely in a tiny plstic box.

This way I can still use all qualities of RemoteGPIO and functionality and recieving status updates from each "remote station" - to my Python code/GUI that you can desing for your need. AND hardware is quite cheap ( RPi zero is less that 10$ inc. relay board ).

All the best

Guy

Comment: Problem with RPi0 as remote station is power consumption. If the place is remote and only battery power is available, it's impossible.

Comment: Power consumption is always an issue. Finally battery will drain. What is your alternative?